# Ideal of Segre product $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need to find the ideal of Segre product  $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$ which is embedding in $\mathbb{P}^{11}$.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you show me how you go that dimension count?  I know that $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^8$, so your dimension count of $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \to 11$ seems a bit low.

Comment: @cactus314 you are right. Indeed, $\phi: \mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2\ \to \mathbb{P}^{80}$. Image of $\phi$ is embeded in $\mathbb{P}^{11}$

Comment: Consider $A:=k[r_0,r_1,r_2][r_3,r_4,r_5][r_6,r_7,r_8][r_9,r_{10},r_{11}]$as coordinate ring.

Answer (score 2):

The Segre map is a product $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^8$ (since $(2 +1)\times (2 +1) - 1 = 5)$ given by a formula:

$$ [x_1, x_2, x_3] \times [y_1, y_2, y_3] = 
\big[
x_1 y_1:  
x_1 y_2: 
x_1 y_3:: 
x_2 y_1: 
x_2 y_2: 
x_2 y_3: 
x_3 y_1:: 
x_3 y_2: 
x_3 y_3 \big] \in \mathbb{P}^{3 \times 3 - 1}$$

So this is an element of  $\mathbb{P}^8$.  We need to find three relations.  These will be the $2 \times 2$ determinants.

$$ \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 y_1 & x_1y_2 \\
x_2 y_1 & x_2y_2  \end{array} 
\right|  = 
\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
x_2 y_2 & x_2y_3 \\
x_3 y_2 & x_3y_3  \end{array} 
\right|  = 
\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
x_3 y_3 & x_3y_1 \\
x_1 y_3 & x_1y_1  \end{array} 
\right|  =  0 $$

These relations don't say a whole lot.  Here's a proof of the first one.  We rearranged the letters and put new parentheses:

$$ (x_1 y_1)(x_2 y_2) - (x_1 y_2)(x_2 y_1) = 0 $$

Then we we use the notation $z_{ij} = x_i y_j$ with $(i,j) \in \{ 1,2,3\} \times \{ 1,2,3\}$ we get the relations of the $z$:

$$ \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
z_{11} & z_{12} \\
z_{21} & z_{22}  \end{array} 
\right|  = 
\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
z_{22} & z_{23} \\
z_{32} & z_{33}  \end{array} 
\right|  = \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
z_{33} & z_{31} \\
z_{13} & z_{11}  \end{array} 
\right|  =  0 $$

This is just from Wikipedia's discussion of the [Segre Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) and I have worked out the case $m = 2$ and $n = 2$.  To analyze your case - we are multiplying four copies of $\mathbb{P}^2$, perhaps we could work in projective space.  The Segre map is:

$$ \varphi: \mathbb{P}(U) \times \mathbb{P}(V) \to \mathbb{P}(U \otimes V) $$

The image of $\varphi$ is the segre map.  The coordinates of $\mathbb{P}(U \otimes V)$ are indexed by $u \otimes v$ where $u$ and $v$ are basis elements of $U$ and $V$. So while the Segre map equations looks arbitrary or complicated at first, they arise from very natural considerations.

These identities suggest you should write the multiplication as a square:

$$ [x_1, x_2, x_3] \times \left[ \begin{array}{c} 
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{array} \right] 
= \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
x_1 y_1 & x_1 y_2 & x_1 y_3 \\ 
x_2 y_1 & x_2 y_2 & x_2 y_3 \\ 
x_3 y_1 & x_3 y_2 & x_3 y_3 
\end{array}\right]
:= \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|c} 
z_{11} & z_{12} & z_{13} \\ 
z_{21} & z_{22} & z_{23} \\ \hline 
z_{31} & z_{32} & z_{33} 
\end{array}\right]
$$

So there are $9$ variables $1$ variable from the projective relation and $\binom{3}{2}  = 3$ relations from setting the determinant [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) to zero, and $9 - 1 - 3 = 5$ dimensions left over.

---

In your case, there is a $3+3+3+3 - 1 = 11$ dimensional object embedded in a $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 = 81$ dimensional space.  So there are 70 relations to find.

Comment: In the first line $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^8$ and $(2+1)\times(2+1)-1=8$